# Antiderivative of $e^x \coth(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, hyperbolic-functions

I want to calculate the antiderivative of $x \mapsto e^x \coth(x)$ for $x > 0$. [Wolfram-Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BPower%5Be%2Cx%5Dcoth%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29%2Cx%5D) tells me that it is equal to $x \mapsto e^x - 2 \operatorname{artanh}(e^x)$. However, this is obviously only defined for $x < 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** We can rewrite this function as $$x\mapsto e^x\coth(x) = \frac{e^x+\tfrac{1}{e^x}}{e^x-\tfrac{1}{e^x}}\cdot e^x$$ Can you recognize this function as taking the form $R(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$ for some function $g$ and rational function $R$, and then find the antiderivative of the rational function $R$ and use the chain rule?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I can reduce the problem to computing the antiderivative of $x \mapsto 1/(x^2-1)$ for $x > 1$, where I am stuck.

Comment: Oh, I see that $2/(x^2-1) = 1/(x-1) - 1/(x+1)$.